# How to run a command in cmd, and open it up to allow input? (Java)

Tags: java, input, cmd, command

I'm making a Swing program which will be used to easily run C++ programs with G++, but I'm stuck on actually running the program. I tried using Runtime.getRuntime() or something like that, but it didn't seem to work. And also, using that only runs the command, and doesn't allow input. Obviously, as it'll run a program, it would need to be able to receive command line input, so is there any way to run a command by opening cmd and then executing the command in that instance of the program, allowing the user to type things in?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the ProcessBuilder class, I think it does what you're asking: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: I don't really get it, could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

> How to run a command in cmd, and open it up to allow input? (Java)

First of all, are you making use of the arguments in the main method?

```
public static void main(String[] args) //<--- arguments will be send to args[x]
{

}
```

If you want your program to be able to receive arguments, you have to handle those received arguments, if not, even if the arguments were passed in. Nothing will happen.

**Example:**

```
class MyFullName{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        if(args.length() != 2)
            system.out.println("2 arguments needed");
        else
            System.out.println("Your fullname is: " + args[0] + " " args[1]);
    }
}
```

The above example is a program which receives the first name and last name and combine it together and printing it out. Arguments you typed will be passed into `args` string array.

**Test run:**

```
javac MyFullName.java
java MyFullName adam smith
Your fullname is adam smith
```

If you are using Windows and do not want to type the commands in the command prompt, you can place those codes in a batch file. Executing the batch file will execute those commands, which will launch your program.

Comment: How would I run the batch file from java? Would I just have to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(batch file path)`?

Comment: @ZacGarby If you are using batch file, I don't think you need to use Runtime.getRuntime anymore. Just direct to the location where your class file is stored and run it. For example: `cd c:/windows/user/folderName`. Then `java class name`.

Comment: I'm not really sure how that answers the question, however I might be misinterpreting it, but what I need is a way to run some commands/a batch file and by doing so, opening cmd to allow input and output from the C++ program.

Answer (score 0):

This sample Java Program executes the 'dir' command reads the output of the dir command prints the results.

```
import java.io.*; 

public class doscmd 
{ 
public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
try 
{ 
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir"); 
p.waitFor(); 
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 
String line=reader.readLine(); 
while(line!=null) 
{ 
System.out.println(line); 
line=reader.readLine(); 
}} 
catch(IOException e1) {} 
catch(InterruptedException e2) {} 

System.out.println("Done"); 
}}
```

Ref:http://www.javasamples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=8

Comment: The problem with that is, because I'm making a program to run C++ files, you would need to be able to do input (cin >>) which means I don't just want to print it out. I thought that the easiest way to allow input would be by running it in cmd.